# Trying to find a set of letters within a string with a loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to make a loop that checks all the cells in column A and if it finds that any of them contains the phrase "ISAW" within a string (like 1314_ISAW_STUFF) then it changes the value of the corresponding cell in column G to "COMPLIANT".

I have the following code, the loop works and the Cells.Find option should work but it doesn't activate any cells with matching criteria.

```
Sub mytestsub()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim i As Integer
sh1.Activate

On Error GoTo MyError
For i = 1 To InStr(ActiveSheet, "ISAW")
    sh1.Cells.Find("ISAW").Activate
    If InStr(ActiveCell, "ISAW") > 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(, 7).Value = "COMPLIANT"
    End If
Next i

MyError:
On Error GoTo -1

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I altered the script Tom generously provided as seen below, but it doesn't seem to be working now.

```
 Sub bugfix()
'QA N/A bugfix'
    Dim fndCell As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Worksheets("Summary").Unprotect
With Worksheets("Summary")
        .Activate


        On Error GoTo MyError
        Set fndCell = .Column(3).Find(what:="ISAW", lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not fndCell Is Nothing Then
         ' uncomment if you really want to visually track the cells
            'fndCell.Activate
            FirstAddress = fndCell.Address
            Do
                fndCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "N/A"
                Set fndCell = .Cells.FindNext(fndCell)
            Loop Until fndCell.Address = FirstAddress
        End If
    End With
Exit Sub
MyError:
    On Error GoTo -1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's almost never a reason to `Activate` or use `ActiveCell` in order to check a certain value, or change another cell's value.
Instead, use fully qualified objects.

Also, using `On Error GoTo MyError` is not necessary in this case, see code below.

**Code**

```
Sub mytestsub()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With sh1
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column "A"
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If InStr(.Range("A" & i).Value2, "ISAW") > 0 Then ' check if current cell in column "A" contains "ISAW"
            .Range("G" & i).Value2 = "COMPLIANT" ' change the value at column "G"
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yep this one works like a charm, I made the necessary alterations to make it work with my macro and now it finally runs through and does what it needs to do. Thank you very much for helping with this!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Find` and `FindNext` to do this. This will find all cells in `Sheet1` that contain `"ISAW"` and update the values in column `G`. Also, with error handling make sure to `Exit Sub` before your error handling process otherwise it'll run whether there is an error or not.

***Updated after comments***

The reason it's not doing anything is because your code actually has an error BUT it is being masked by your `On Error GoTo MyError`. I've updated with a fixed code

```
Sub bugfix()
    'QA N/A bugfix'
    Dim fndCell As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String

    With Worksheets("Summary")
        .Unprotect
        .Activate
        On Error GoTo MyError
        Set fndCell = .Columns(3).Find(what:="ISAW", lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not fndCell Is Nothing Then
         ' uncomment if you really want to visually track the cells
            'fndCell.Activate
            FirstAddress = fndCell.Address
            Do
                fndCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "N/A"
                Set fndCell = .Columns(3).FindNext(fndCell)
            Loop Until fndCell.Address = FirstAddress
        End If
    End With
    Exit Sub
MyError:
    On Error GoTo -1
End Sub
```

Comment: Not see why you would need to `Activate` the sheet ? or use `On Error GoTo MyError` ?

Comment: You're right you don't need it. But kept it in as OP may be using it to navigate to this worksheet and may be extending the error handling at a later date. You're right though - It doesn't do anything for the rest of the code.

Comment: Does this code check all the cells on the sheet or only cells in column A?

Comment: It will do all cells in the sheet but can be restricted to column A by changing `.Cells` to `.Columns(1)` in the search lines.

Comment: Odd, when I tried the code on an empty sheet it seems to work perfectly. But when I added it to the macro I am using it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I made sure to unprotect the sheet before running it to no avail.

Comment: Make sure the sheet name matches - You will need to update the `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` to your sheet if it doesn't match

Comment: The sheet name matches but to no avail. I edited my initial question to contain your code which I altered to fit my macro.

Comment: I think you've edited @ShaiRado code instead of your question

Comment: Yeah...I am so bad at navigating this site. In the meantime your code works perfectly on a generic excel sheet so I upvoted you, however I tried @ShaiRado -s code and after altering it it works for my macro too so I marked it as the answer. Thank you for your help either way!

Comment: I've just updated my answer with your code fixed. You had an error which you error handling was masking. I'd advise using `Find` instead of looping through everything as it is more efficient.

Comment: Okay thanks for the pointer, I took note of both methods and try to apply the best working one in future cases. I thought that the error handling was essential for looping through cells, but apparently it is not haha.

Answer (score 0):

I can appreciate there could be good reason to use VBA but May I suggest a formula as an option, in first data cell in column G and then copied down

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND("ISAW",A1,1)),"","COMPLIANT")
```

This looks for your string if it finds it then its start position is returned, if it doesn't then it returns `#VALUE`. The encapsulating `IF` statement converts this to COMPLIIANT or empty.

Comment: Sadly I cannot use the formula as the G column's cells already contain a formula and the number of values in the column G is random